# Jquery dragging- Not working when mouse pointer of out of div

Tags: jquery

The drag function stops when the mouse pointer is out of the parent div while dragging. I need to bring the mouse pointer inside the div to continue dragging. Is there any solution for this?

Comment: Are you using jquery UI draggable?  It shouldn't do this.  Sounds more like you're rolling your own.  In which case I would suggest draggable, otherwise we'll need to see your code.

Answer (score 0):

if you are trying to drag something in all window try this:

```
$( ".selector" ).draggable({ containment: 'window' });
```

or any other element instead of 'window' like:

'parent', 'document', 'window', [x1, y1, x2, y2].

Comment: He didn't say he was using jQuery UI. I'm having this same problem and not using jQuery UI.